# Buffer-Overflow in simple C program

Tags: c

I wrote a C program which checks if a certain password is entered and returns a file called Secret when the password is correct (at least that 's what it is supposed to do). 
During testing I found that it is not behaving as intended when entering exactly 15 times the number 1 (111111111111111) as input, the file Secret is shown even tough this is not the password stored in the file.

I added the sanitize method which removes all non alphabetic characters but apparently that did not fix it.

I do not really understand why I get an Overflow and which variable(s) (and their memory) are affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings in c must have the last char as being '\0' (null terminator). This means that, when you do an allocation like this:

```
char pass[15];
```

you are indeed allocation 14 characters and 1 for null terminator.

`strcpy` works based on this. If your strings does not have a terminator you will get an buffer overflow.

Looking at the password of 15 1's it becomes clear that you are not letting space to put a null terminator

To avoid that, start using [strncpy](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html) function and its family

Comment: Thank you very much! Using the strncpy function indeed looks like the safer option.

Is it possible to tell which exact variable is overflown leading to the secret file being returned? I have difficulties understanding what is happening on the stack frame leading to this behavior of the program.

Comment: Your best friend here is a debugger, but looking at your program, it seems me that `strcpy(pass, str);` is the villain